# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productName')

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have a `CartSummary` component where I show the products that are added to the cart. When the user triggers `addProduct` method, the state reloads and re-fetchs the cart from the server. In short, I save the cart information in database, when somenone add/remove a product from the cart I reload the cart. However, I get the the above error. It might be caused by asynchronous programming. I tried to use loader before the cart information arrives to the client side, but it didn't work. Also, the state is not reloaded when I add a new product to the cart. I tried to log the cart info to the console each time(marked in CartSummary class), it seems the `cartItems` is empty at first, but then it refilled.That's why I made a codition such that `cart.cartItems.length>0 ?.... : ....` Still not working.

**CartSummary** component where I show the cart details to the user.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Badge, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, Spinner, UncontrolledDropdown} from "reactstrap";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {cartActions} from "../redux/slice/cartSlice";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"
import alertify from "alertifyjs";
import {fetchCart} from "../redux/thunk/cartActionThunk";
import {PageSpinner} from "./spinner/Spinner";

const CartSummary = () => {


    const cart = useSelector(state => (state.cartStore.cart))
    const isLoading = useSelector(state => (state.uiStore.isLoading))
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const handleRemoveFromCart = (product) => {
        dispatch(cartActions.removeFromCart(product.id))
        alertify.error(product.productName + " removed from the cart", 1)

    }
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [dispatch])

    console.log(cart) // HERE I LOG THE CART 
    return (
        <div>
            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    Cart
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    {

                        isLoading ?

                            <PageSpinner></PageSpinner>
                            :
                            cart.cartItems.map((item) => (
                                <DropdownItem
                                    style={{
                                        justifyContent: "space-between",
                                        display: "flex",
                                        alignContent: "center",
                                        margin: 10
                                    }}
                                    key={item.id}>
                                    {item.product.productName}
                                    <Badge color="success">{item.totalQuantity}</Badge>
                                </DropdownItem>
                            ))

                    }
                    <DropdownItem divider/>
                    <DropdownItem style={{textAlign: "end"}}> <Badge
                        color="success">${cart.totalPrice}</Badge></DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem style={{textAlign: "center"}} onClick={() => navigate("/cart-details")}>Show
                        cart details</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CartSummary;
```

**Cart Actions Thunk**

```
import {API_URL} from "../../const/url";
import {cartActions} from "../slice/cartSlice";
import alertify from "alertifyjs";
import {uiActions} from "../slice/uiSlice";


export const addToCart = (product) => {


    const productDto = {
        "id": product.id,
        "productName": product.productName,
        "quantityPerUnit": product.quantityPerUnit,
        "unitPrice": product.unitPrice,
        "unitsInStock": product.unitsInStock,
        "categoryId": product.category.id
    }


    const userId = 1;
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(true))

        fetch(API_URL + '/cartItem?userId=' + userId, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(productDto)
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error("Couldn't add " + productDto.productName + " to the cart.")
            }

            return response.json()
        }).then((result) => {
            dispatch(cartActions.addProduct(result))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))
            alertify.success(productDto.productName + " added successfully.")

        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch(uiActions.setError(err))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))
            alertify.error(err.message)

        })
    }

}

export const fetchCart = () => {
    const userId = 1;
    return (dispatch)=>{
        dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(true))

        fetch(API_URL + '/cartItem?userId=' + userId, {
            method: 'GET'
        }).then((response)=>{
            if(!response.ok){
                throw Error("Couldn't fetch cart data")
            }
            return response.json()
        }).then((result)=>{
            dispatch(cartActions.fetchCart(result))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))

        }).catch((err)=>{
            dispatch(uiActions.setError(err))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))

            alertify.error(err.message)
        })
    }
}

export const removeFromCart = (product) => {

    return (dispatch) => {

        fetch(API_URL + '/')
    }
}
```

**CartSlice**

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: {cart: {cartItems: [], totalPrice: 0, totalQuantity: 0}},
    reducers: {
        //payload is product
        addProduct(state, action) {
            state.cart.cartItems.push(action)

        },
        //payload is product id
        removeFromCart(state, action) {
            const existingCartItem = state.cart.cartItemList.find((cartItem) => cartItem.product.id === action.payload)


            state.cart.totalPrice -= existingCartItem.totalPrice;
            state.cart.totalQuantity--;
            state.cart.cartItemList = state.cart.cartItemList.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.product.id !== action.payload)
        },
        fetchCart(state, action) {
            state.cart = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const cartActions = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice;
```

Json structure for cart

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 12.5,
            "product": {
                "id": 3,
                "productName": "Scottish Longbreads",
                "quantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 8 pieces",
                "unitPrice": 12.5,
                "unitsInStock": 6,
                "categoryId": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 31.0,
            "product": {
                "id": 10,
                "productName": "Ikura",
                "quantityPerUnit": "12 - 200 ml jars",
                "unitPrice": 31.0,
                "unitsInStock": 31,
                "categoryId": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "totalQuantity": 2,
            "totalPrice": 69.6,
            "product": {
                "id": 4,
                "productName": "Mozzarella di Giovanni",
                "quantityPerUnit": "24 - 200 g pkgs.",
                "unitPrice": 34.8,
                "unitsInStock": 14,
                "categoryId": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 37.0,
            "product": {
                "id": 6,
                "productName": "Queso Manchego La Pastora",
                "quantityPerUnit": "10 - 500 g pkgs.",
                "unitPrice": 37.0,
                "unitsInStock": 86,
                "categoryId": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 38.0,
            "product": {
                "id": 8,
                "productName": "Queso Manchego La Pastora",
                "quantityPerUnit": "10 - 500 g pkgs.",
                "unitPrice": 38.0,
                "unitsInStock": 86,
                "categoryId": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 33.25,
            "product": {
                "id": 5,
                "productName": "Wimmers gute Semmelknödel",
                "quantityPerUnit": "20 bags x 4 pieces",
                "unitPrice": 33.25,
                "unitsInStock": 22,
                "categoryId": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 25,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 13.0,
            "product": {
                "id": 2,
                "productName": "Original Frankfurer grüne So",
                "quantityPerUnit": "12 boxes",
                "unitPrice": 13.0,
                "unitsInStock": 11,
                "categoryId": 8
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalQuantity": 7,
    "totalPrice": 234.35
}
```

Comment: `item.product.productName` -> `item.productName`

Comment: Add a `useEffect` that depends on the `cart` object. Then wherever you're using the cart, you can add the loader with a check if `cart` is an object or not. This will make React render the loader until the cart object has been fetched and populated. Also, logging the `cart` object where you are right now will always be empty because the calls are asynchronous so you may want to log it inside the new `useEffect` that i suggested above.

Comment: @Konrad I added the json structure at the end. It must be `item.product.productName`

Comment: @need_to_know_now how can i add cart in `useEffect`  in `CartSummary` component ? My useEffect doesn't rely on cart. If I add `cart` in `useEffect`, it keeps calling `fetchCart` method.