# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined product

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am getting the above error. I tried to log each item to the console.. The result is the following. I couldn't figure out how it is possible. I think the marked item type causes the above error. Why the items(cart items) differentiate from each other. I marked the place in `CartSummary` where I print out those items.

[image]

**CartSummary**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Badge, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, Spinner, UncontrolledDropdown} from "reactstrap";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {cartActions} from "../redux/slice/cartSlice";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"
import alertify from "alertifyjs";
import {fetchCart} from "../redux/thunk/cartActionThunk";
import {PageSpinner} from "./spinner/Spinner";

const CartSummary = () => {


    const cart = useSelector(state => (state.cartStore.cart))
    const isLoading = useSelector(state => (state.uiStore.isLoading))
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const handleRemoveFromCart = (product) => {
        dispatch(cartActions.removeFromCart(product.id))
        alertify.error(product.productName + " removed from the cart", 1)

    }
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchCart())
    }, [dispatch])


    return (
        <div>
            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                    Cart
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    {
                            cart.cartItems.map((item) => {

                                console.log('item', item) // HERE WHERE I PRINT OUT
                                    return  <DropdownItem
                                        style={{
                                            justifyContent: "space-between",
                                            display: "flex",
                                            alignContent: "center",
                                            margin: 10
                                        }}
                                        key={item.id}>
                                        {item.product.productName}
                                        <Badge color="success">{item.totalQuantity}</Badge>
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                }
                            )



                    }
                    <DropdownItem divider/>
                    <DropdownItem style={{textAlign: "end"}}> <Badge
                        color="success">${cart.totalPrice}</Badge></DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem style={{textAlign: "center"}} onClick={() => navigate("/cart-details")}>Show
                        cart details</DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CartSummary;
```

**Cart Action Thunk**

```
import {API_URL} from "../../const/url";
import {cartActions} from "../slice/cartSlice";
import alertify from "alertifyjs";
import {uiActions} from "../slice/uiSlice";


export const addToCart = (product) => {


    const productDto = {
        "id": product.id,
        "productName": product.productName,
        "quantityPerUnit": product.quantityPerUnit,
        "unitPrice": product.unitPrice,
        "unitsInStock": product.unitsInStock,
        "categoryId": product.category.id
    }


    const userId = 1;
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(true))

        fetch(API_URL + '/cartItem?userId=' + userId, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(productDto)
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error("Couldn't add " + productDto.productName + " to the cart.")
            }

            return response.json()
        }).then((result) => {
            dispatch(cartActions.addProduct(result))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))
            alertify.success(productDto.productName + " added successfully.")

        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch(uiActions.setError(err))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))
            alertify.error(err.message)

        })
    }

}

export const fetchCart = () => {
    const userId = 1;
    return (dispatch)=>{
        dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(true))

        fetch(API_URL + '/cartItem?userId=' + userId, {
            method: 'GET'
        }).then((response)=>{
            if(!response.ok){
                throw Error("Couldn't fetch cart data")
            }
            return response.json()
        }).then((result)=>{
            dispatch(cartActions.fetchCart(result))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))
        }).catch((err)=>{
            dispatch(uiActions.setError(err))
            dispatch(uiActions.setIsLoading(false))
            alertify.error(err.message)
        })
    }
}

export const removeFromCart = (product) => {

    return (dispatch) => {

        fetch(API_URL + '/')
    }
}
```

**Cart JSON structure**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "id": 22,
            "totalQuantity": 1,
            "totalPrice": 37.0,
            "product": {
                "id": 6,
                "productName": "Queso Manchego La Pastora",
                "quantityPerUnit": "10 - 500 g pkgs.",
                "unitPrice": 37.0,
                "unitsInStock": 86,
                "categoryId": 6
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalQuantity": 1,
    "totalPrice": 37.0
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question you asked yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661239/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-productname How is this any different?